# performance considerations of hashValue in swift protocol Hashable

Tags: swift, hashset, hashable

Besides being a unique integer are there any performance considerations for the selection of a `hashValue` in a swift `Hashable` Type that may be inserted into a `Set`? For instance will the size of the integer values I choose affect the size of the backing array? i.e. if I assign a `hashValue` of `4000` to a `Hashable` type and insert that into a `Set` will the backing array need to be at least `4000` in length?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here by "backing array" or why `hashValue` would have any relationship to it. (I suspect the answer is "no" but I don't really understand the question.)

Comment: I'm thinking of `Set` in particular. Sorry for the omission

Comment: I assume you think Sets are implemented as an array where the hash value is the index? That's not how they're implemented. They're hash tables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. The hash value itself is fairly irrelevant. Ideally it is random across the entire Int space so there aren't collisions and the table is balanced (can't remember if they use a binary tree or not; you can look here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb)

Comment: But doesn't a hash table need a dynamic backing array? Maybe I have a misunderstanding of how a hash table works. The wiki article uses the hash values to index into "buckets" which I assume was an array.

Comment: At the end of the day, all of computer memory is one long Array, so sure, and most data structures have some kind of liberally indexed memory, but dig into how hash tables are built. It has nothing to do with the size of the value you return for the hash.

Answer (score 5):

`hashValue` does not have to be a unique. In the vast majority of cases it *can't* be unique (any type that is larger than 64-bits will necessarily have more possible states than its hash). You don't choose the size of the integer. It will always be `Int` (which is the machine word size).

`hashValue` should be fast, however, and ideally O(1). It is often used to help optimize equality checking (which may be very slow).

The simplest implementation of `hashValue` is:

```
var hashValue: Int { return 1 }
```

This is a perfectly valid hash. It's not a particularly *good* hash, but it meets all the requirements. It is fast to calculate, and all equal objects will have equal hashes (which is a requirement; the converse is not required: equal hashes may not imply equal objects).